# Problem with NextUI Dynamic items using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nextui

I have the following code on a React proyect using typescript:

```
  interface ICountry {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  }
...

const [countries, setCountries] = useState<ICountry[] | undefined>();
...
       <Dropdown>
          <DropdownTrigger>
            <Button variant="bordered">Open Menu</Button>
          </DropdownTrigger>
          <DropdownMenu aria-label="Static Actions" items={countries}>
            {(country) => (
              <DropdownItem
                key={country.id}
                value={country.id}
                onPress={(e: any) => setCountry(e.currentTarget.value)}
              >
                {country.name}
              </DropdownItem>
            )}
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
```

The problem is that country is a generic object and I get this error :

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'.

[image]

How can I type *country* to be able to use the properties of the objects and stop getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Fought this one for a bit myself after trying to create a custom dropdown component with a generic items type. No matter what I did, the item argument is always of type object. To silence this I ended with the following. Would like to know if others have been able to solve this.

Custom component constrains items prop to type "Item"

```
<DropdownMenu aria-label={ariaLabel} items={items}>
    {(item) => <DropdownItem key={(item as Item).key}>{(item as Item).value</DropdownItem>}
</DropdownMenu>
```